# hidden-xs hiding div on print in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image]In MVC project, we are using bootstrap.

There is need to hide div for xs devices and have to show at time of print and desktop.

Code is in below as:

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
    --Content--
</div>
```

But it is hiding div at time printing to window.

Comment: code is as <div class="hidden-xs"> content </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div class="hidden-xs print-visible"> content </div> 
@media print{
  .print-visible{
       display: block !important;
   }
}
```

Add a additional user defined class to hidden-xs div(as above) and in your style sheet add the above rule. Hope it fixes your issue.

Comment: But the intending of div doing some irregular behavior, as You can see the screen shot (updated in question).

Answer (score -1):

> Bootstrap provides some handful helper classes, for faster mobile-friendly development. These can be used for showing and hiding content by device via media query, combined with large, small, and medium devices.

```
  <div class = "container">
   <div class = "row visible-on">
        <div>             
             <span class = "hidden-xs">Extra small</span>
             <span class = "visible-xs">✔ Visible on x-small</span>
      </div>
  </div>  
</div>
```